# Let $\tau'$ be the weak topology generated by $S\subset\ C( X,R )$. Do we have $S = C( X, R )$ with respect to this topology?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, weak-topology

Let $(X,\tau)$ be a compact topological space, and let $\large\tau'$  be the weak topology generated by some subset $S \subset \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$ which seperates points.

I need to show that $\large\tau$ = $\large\tau'$.

I tried to show first that **with respect to $\large\tau'$** it follows that $S=\mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$, i.e $f:X\rightarrow R $ is continuous **with respect to $\large\tau'$** iff $f \in S$ .

But I'm not sure if this statement is correct (if it's correct I know how to finish the proof using it)

Comment: The question was badly written and is is not clear, although I tried to edit it. I hope I understood correctly. What does $S = \mathcal(X,\mathbb{R})$ with respect to some topology mean? Do you mean that $S$ defines the same initial topology as $\mathcal(X,\mathbb{R})$? Do you want to prove that $\tau'=\tau$?

Comment: @geetha290krm The statement $S = \mathcal{C}(X,\mathbb{R})$ is clearly false! For example when $X=[0,1]$ and $S$ is the set of all monomials $x \mapsto x^n$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan You are right. I didn't notice that part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

In some texts, compact means compact and Hausdorff. I will assume that $X$ is compact and Hausdorff. Then $(X,\tau')$ is also Hausdorff: I will let you check this, using the fact that $S$ separates points.

By definition $\tau'\subseteq \tau$. Consider the identity map $i: (X,\tau)\to (X, \tau')$. This is a continuous bijection. It maps closed sets to closed sets because closed subsets are compact (and continuous images of compact sets are compact, hence also closed). Hence, its inverse is continuous. This says that  $\tau\subseteq \tau'$.